# preg_replace_callback regex match all urls and avoid images

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex to match all urls and works great:

```
$regex ='@((https?://)([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.\,]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@';                           
return preg_replace_callback( $regex, 'replacing' , $content );
```

I need to avoid match urls inside : `src="***"` and `<a href="">***</>` want to keep the text but replace url.

I've tried : adding negation to my regex:

```
$regex ='@((?!src="|?!>)(https?://)([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.\,]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@';
```

first negation when url is startin with src="
second negation is when is between a href a href >

Any ideas to make it work?

Comment: What is `(?!src="|?!>)`? Maybe, you wanted `(?<!src=")`.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting place is [lib_autolink](https://github.com/iamcal/lib_autolink) which handles the `<a>` case and could be easily adapted for the `<img>` case. It is non-trivial and perhaps impossible to do this in a single regexp unless you can guarantee that the HTML is perfectly valid (no stray quotation marks in text, etc).